# AWS Cloudformation: Is it possible to access user id inside a Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to auto-tag certain AWS resources defined in a CloudFormation template with the user who uses the template to create a stack. Is it possible to access any sort of user id in the template?

Comment: Is `AWS::AccountId` enough or do you want the IAM user performing the stack creation? What should it be on update?

Comment: I would like the IAM user performing the creation.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there is a way to get an updating user as well, but accessing the creating user would be a win.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

AWS services are tied to AWS Accounts. Once IAM confirms that a particular user has permission to make an API call, resources that are generated become associated with an Account rather than a particular User. For example, it is not possible to look at an EC2 instance and determine who launched the instance.

This information is, however, available in **AWS CloudTrail**, but that is more of an audit log — it does not provide the user information back to the service.

So, I suspect that a stack is not provided with information about the User that launched it.

Answer (score -1):

There is one way of doing it, but it isn't pretty and there is a caveat.

You can run a bash script like the below on an ec2 instance:

```
AWS_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
USER_ID=`aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Arn'`
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}" --tags 'Key=CreatedBy,Value="${USER_ID}"' --region eu-west-1
```

That will tag the current instance with the name of the user that run the CLI on that instance.

The caveat is however that the CLI needs to be run by the user - and not a role, so your users keys will have to be copied to the server - and then removed again at the end of the script.

Not ideal, but it gives you an option.